# arch openldap authentication failure

Tags: ldap, openldap

I setup the openldap, all look fine but i cant setup authentication,

```
#getent shadow | grep user                         
user:*:::::::
tuser:*:::::::
tuser2:*:::::::

#getent passwd | grep user
git:!:999:999:git daemon user:/:/bin/bash
user:x:10000:2000:Test User:/home/user/:/bin/zsh
tuser:x:10000:2000:Test User:/home/user/:/bin/zsh
tuser2:x:10002:2000:Test User:/home/tuser2/:/bin/zsh
```

from root i can login as a one of these users

```
#su - tuser2
su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/tuser2/: No such file or directory
10:24 tuser2@juliet:/root
```

i cant login via ssh also passwd is not working

```
#ldapwhoami -h 192.168.10.156 -D "uid=user,ou=People,dc=xcl,dc=ie"
ldap_bind: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
    additional info: unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed
10:30 root@juliet:~
#ldapwhoami -h 192.168.10.156 -D "uid=user,ou=People,dc=xcl,dc=ie" -W
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

typed password by me is correct

/etc/openldap/slapd.conf
    access to dn.base="" by * read
    access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
    access to *
      by self write
      by users read
      by anonymous read

```
access to *
  by dn="uid=root,ou=Roles,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by users read
  by anonymous auth
access to attrs=userPassword,gecos,description,loginShell
  by self write

access to attrs="userPassword"
  by dn="uid=root,ou=Roles,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by anonymous auth
  by self write
  by * none
access to *
  by dn="uid=root,ou=Roles,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by dn="uid=achmiel,ou=People,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by * search

access to attrs=userPassword
  by self =w
  by anonymous auth
access to *
  by self write
  by users read

database        hdb
suffix          "dc=xcl,dc=ie"
rootdn          "cn=root,dc=xcl,dc=ie"
rootpw          "{SSHA}AM14+..."
```

there are some parts of that conf file
/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
looks :

```
BASE dc=xcl,dc=ie
URI ldap://192.168.10.156/
TLS_REQCERT  allow
TIMELIMIT    2
```

so my question is what i am missing that ldap not allow me login by using password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solve the problem by removing those ACL's queries

```
access to *
  by dn="uid=root,ou=Roles,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by users read
  by anonymous auth
access to attrs=userPassword,gecos,description,loginShell
  by self write

access to attrs="userPassword"
  by dn="uid=root,ou=Roles,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by anonymous auth
  by self write
  by * none
access to *
  by dn="uid=root,ou=Roles,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by dn="uid=achmiel,ou=People,dc=xcl,dc=ie" write
  by * search
```

i did more changes but anyway those changes doesnt fix that problem until i remove mentioned ACL's